# \footenote color is changed, and without hyperlinking

Tags: hyperref

I have my bibliography / sections labeled for hyperreferencing and all of that.... and everywhere else there is `\footnote[#]{reference}`

When I make the pdf here is what I get: The pdf has the exact small, raised footnote markers that I want but they are all blue and without hyperlinking to the bibliography. Instead of that they send me to the top of the page.

Here is what I tried to do so far: I have replaced `\footnote[#]{reference}` with `\footnote[\hyperref[bib:#]{[#]}]{reference}` and I have replaced `\footnote[#]{reference}` with `\hyperref[bib:#]{\footnote[#]{reference}}`

Neither of them function how I want them to. \hyperref does not publish a pdf with \footnote as the text and `\footnote[\hyperref]{reference}` sends me to the top of the page again.

What should I be doing instead of that to get the raised footenote # to send to the bibliography??

The following tex makes a section with a footnote in it that ought to link to the bibliography reference but instead links to the footnote at the bottom of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{vntex}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\def\mathbi#1{\textbf{\em #1}}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}

\begin{document}

\section{language genre}

A close game will definitely be played today.\footnote{\hyperref[bib:1]{1}}\\

\newpage
\section{bibliography}
\label{bib:1} $[1]$ dan gaming and that.\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question would be a _lot_ easier to understand if it included a small but complete document that showed the problem so people could debug it and test answers.

Comment: How does your desired output differ from what `\cite` gives you?

Comment: I don't have experience with cite, really I've only used tex for 3 years because it looks good .

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you load `tikz` and `graphicx` twice?